# Create chainable Object dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I would like to create a chain Object dynamically created that could look something like this:

```
Config.API.Host
```

My point is to **build a simple interface that could be easily extended** (maybe not the best approach (?)).
Already tried working `ExpandoObject`, but doesn't helped me since I want to turn the properties publicly exposed.
I am new on C# and don't even know if this is actually possible.

Done so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ExpandoTest
{
    public class Config
    {
        private Dictionary<string, IConfigContract> options;

        public Config()
        {
            options.Add("API", new API());
        }

        public ExpandoObject Build()
        {
            dynamic exp = new ExpandoObject();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IConfigContract> entry in options)
            {
                exp[entry] = value;
            }

            return exp;
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace ExpandoTest
{
    public class API : IConfigContract // empty Interface, just for use case
    {
        public string Foo = "Bar";
    }
}
```

```
using System;

namespace ExpandoTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var log = new Config().Build();

            Console.WriteLine(log.API.Foo);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Long story short: C# is statically typed (that is: types are known at compile time). You can't make an object that dynamically creates properties on the fly but also knows about them at compile time. You either need to manually create a class that contains the properties you need, or accept that you can't verify them at compile time and use an `ExpandoObject`, along with the risk that you made a typo and your program will crash.

Comment: In C# this kind of thing is typically dealt with by some form of static code generation that produces real C# code that the compiler can use.